# Flash Professional CC stuck on publishing swf from huge .fla

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

My .fla is about 600mb big due to enormous amount of library objects. 
I have 15.500 objects in library and most of them are images. This is probably bad practice, but my client required to have these images inside of it instead of loading them dynamically from some external source.

I have already reduced the size of the images as much as possible while still maintaining good quality.

I'm publishing for Flash Player, and already tried different versions.
Basicly my app is fairly simple test paper app, populating 20 test papers with simple multiple choise questions. Each test paper has 150 questions divided into 4 sections, and each question contains 1 question image and 4 answer images to choose from. After user picks his/her answer, these image instances are being deleted and new ones are being created.

I've heard that there's magical limit of 16.000 for everything like instances and so on, so it should stay right about under it as the code itself is quite simple and there's not many other instances after these images.

Besides my ugly file size, I'm also pushing all these images from library into arrays in a loop:
(linkage names are for example "**Paper1_Chem_Q1_C.jpg**", and "**_X**" marks the correct answer - that's why I unshift that one)

```
var sectionLengths:Array = [40,40,45,25];
var prefixes:Array = ["Phys","Chem","Maths","Eng_Reas"];
var prefixes2:Array = ["A","B","C","D"];
for(var p:int = 0; p<20; p++){ //test papers loop
    for(var s:int = 0; s<4; s++){ //sections loop
        var fillQArray:Array = this["tp"+(p+1)+"section"+(s+1)+"questions"];
        var fillAArray:Array = this["tp"+(p+1)+"section"+(s+1)+"answers"];

        for(var q:int = 0; q<sectionLengths[s]; q++){ //question loop
            if(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.hasDefinition(String("Paper"+(p+1)+"_"+prefixes[s]+"_Q"+(q+1)))){
                fillQArray.push(getDefinitionByName("Paper"+(p+1)+"_"+prefixes[s]+"_Q"+(q+1)) as Class);
                var qa:Array = new Array();
                for(var a:int = 0; a<4; a++){ //answers loop
                    if(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.hasDefinition(String("Paper"+(p+1)+"_"+prefixes[s]+"_Q"+(q+1)+"_"+prefixes2[a]))){
                        qa.push(getDefinitionByName("Paper"+(p+1)+"_"+prefixes[s]+"_Q"+(q+1)+"_"+prefixes2[a]));
                    }else if(ApplicationDomain.currentDomain.hasDefinition(String("Paper"+(p+1)+"_"+prefixes[s]+"_Q"+(q+1)+"_"+prefixes2[a]+"_X"))){
                        qa.unshift(getDefinitionByName("Paper"+(p+1)+"_"+prefixes[s]+"_Q"+(q+1)+"_"+prefixes2[a]+"_X"));
                    }
                }
                fillAArray.push(qa);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This loop surely does the job, but takes some time to run. Also, I predefine a LOT of arrays before it, so can this be another potential issue?

During development I've tested everything with few test papers, and it all worked like a charm, but now when I imported all the rest of the images, it gets stuck on publish. I left it to publish for the whole night, but now at morning it's once again stuck and I have to kill Flash process in order to quit it.

I have also increased memory amount from jvm.ini already to 2048m, so it doesn't give anymore the warning dialog regarding to too small JVM memory.

All suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: Maybe you can first prepare a SWC out of all or part of the image set, then inport the precompiled SWC into your project, then try compiling again. But it's quite possible that you have hit a 32-bit limit on the compiler memory (that is, to compile the SWF compiler wants more than 2GB of memory) and it hangs due to untested behavior

Comment: turn off compiler warnings in as3 settings.

Comment: Why does the client want to have it in the fla? Is there some particular reason? I seriously doubt he wants it for web. It is indeed a horrible practice.

Comment: @Fygo, you're right - it will be a exe projector, tho it's still a horribly bad solution.
**BotMaster**, thanks, but didn't help with the main issue.
**Vesper**, SWC solution seems promising, I'm now trying it! Tho I messed up the first SWC's as I didn't realize they also need classnames for themselves, but slowly creating new ones now. (Flash seems to die while publishing big swc's, but after couple hours of waiting it luckily finishes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working, thanks to Vesper!
Here's detailed instructions for Flash Professional CC (so detailed becouse this was all new to me, and I spent almost 2 days for this failing multiple times):

### Step 1 - Publish SWC:

1. Create empty .fla and import your images to library. Select all the
   images and open properties with mouse2 button. At **ActionScript** tab
   select **Export for ActionScript**. Make sure that also **Export in frame 1** is activated.
2. Define a Classname for your project at **Properties panel**, for example: *images_swc*.
3. Go to Publish Settings and publish only SWC.

**Notes:**

- In my case I had to create 3 SWC files becouse of the amount of images (15000+).
- While adding/removing large amount of images to/from library, and while publishing a SWC, Flash Professional stopped responding and it looked like a crash, but in 30-60mins it succesfully finished!
- When it was over an hour in "not responding" -state, I killed Flash process and tried with smaller amount of images.
- First I created my "empty" .fla by removing everything but images from my main project, but somehow it didn't export correct images during SWC publish. But after I Saved As.. my image project, it worked like a charm.
- Always when Flash notified about low JVM memory, I doubled the memory value in jvm.ini and started over. (Had eventually 4096m.)

### Step 2 - Use SWC in your main project:

- **File** -> **Publish Settings** -> **Advanced ActionScript 3.0 Settings** (wrench -icon at top-right-corner) -> **Library path** tab -> Click **Browse to SWC file**, locate your SWC and click **OK**.
- Create empty .as file and type every image classname into it. Idea here is to mention all the images from SWC so that compiler understands that you want to include them in your main project. e.g:

  ```
  package {   
    public class Assets {       
      image_1;
      image_2;
      image_3;
    }
  }
  ```
- In your main project, include Assets.as and your SWC-file(s):

  ```
  import Assets;
  import images_swc;
  ```
- Refer to your images with:

  ```
  getDefinitionByName("image_1")
  ```

**Final notes:**

- If you forget your "SWC classname", change the extension of your SWC file to .zip, open it, and you'll find your classname and other details from the xml file inside of it.
- To get filenames of large amount of images for your .as file (assuming you have same classnames and filenames for your images), you can use windows command prompt and "**dir /s > filename.txt**" -command to gether filenames into txt-file. Myself I used free version of [Directory List & Print](http://www.infonautics.ch/directorylistprint/) which also finds files from subfolders, pasted the file list into Assets.as and used Find & Replace functionality in Flash to replace "**.jpg**" with "**;**".

So, I had over 15000 images, turned them into 3 SWC files = 15-20 megs per SWC, and my final .swf was around 55 megs - and it was compiled in couple minutes, which makes this pretty perfect solution for my project.

@Vesper, thanks again! :)